# How do I narrow down this TypeScript interface?

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript interface like this:

```
export interface User {
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  photoURL?: string;
  email?: string;
  phoneNumber?: string;
  uid: string;
}
```

And I have a variable that is typed like this:

```
const user: boolean | User
```

Now I want to narrow it down using this:

```
if (typeof user === 'User') {
  //Do some things with the User object that are not possible with a boolean
}
```

But I am getting this TypeScript error:

```
This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"' and '"User"' have no overlap. ts(2367)
```

I have also tried this:

```
if (user instanceof 'User') {
   //Do some things with the User object that are not possible with a boolean
}
```

But then it throws this TypeScript error:

```
The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type. ts(2359)
```

How do I narrow the variable down for the `User` type?

Comment: Well, the easiest would probably be `if (typeof user !== "boolean")` or you can add a user defined [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Comment: Since `user` can only be a boolean or `User`, you can just check if it is a typeof boolean. If it’s not then it’s definitely `User`.

Comment: By the way, I would love for JS to (one day) include access to meta- (type-) information at runtime for reasons just like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator evaluates to expressions which include an enumeration of strings, amongst which `"User"` will never be included.

Reverse your conditional logic:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgVQGc04BvAKDjnQSkJgDlMBbYAfgC456pkBzANyU4AG0z0mrTtxi8kg4QBMEhMGICek9lx78hVMAAsIMCPgBKAGWm75+uMGaYEIm7L3CjEJMAYBXZgAjNDc5BSo-BEUddztyAF9yckVgbDEoPGxvejg-YiguQIgIEWBMJDgAHwJ8oXIEdDgAChh1MGAIRrySAEIAXj64AHIikrKkIYBKMmFuqAE4AHpFmrQE8mARYhmI2qWV0dLyhKA)

```ts
if (typeof user !== 'boolean') {
  user; // User
}
else {
  user; // boolean
}
```

While this works for your case, where the discrimination is binary, in the case where more types are possible, you will find that using a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) is quite helpful.